# Rails - Hot Swap Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, hotswap

I'm getting daily dumps for a table(lets stay students table) from an external source. In order to reduce downtime while the table is being truncated and updated with the new data, I'm planning to maintain two copies of this table(students_1 and students_2). 
Both these need to be mapped with Student model on an alternating daily basis. So if today I am using data from students_1, tomorrow, once data has been entered to students_2, I'll need to switch seamlessly to that one.

So my questions are
1) Is this approach good enough or is there a better one ?
2) For hot swapping tables, is it fine to just maintain a file indicating the current table being used and then set_table_name via a method which reads this particular file ? Is there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as part of your data loading strategy, i wouldn't mess with storing table names or using non standard table names. After data is done loading, execute a table rename command instead, it is done atomically and should not interrupt your app.

```
RENAME TABLE students TO students_secondary_temp, students_secondary TO students, students_secondary_temp TO students_secondary;
```